# How To find If this Array has duplicate object which Has another array inside it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to know the duplicate data regardless of the Id.

This is the array:-

```
const myArray = [
  {id: "sjdh1", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["try","test","test"]},
  {id: "sjdh2", userName: "user 2"  , Message: ["test","try","test"]},
  {id: "sjdh3", userName: "user 3"  , Message: ["test"]}, 
  {id: "sjdh4", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["dummy"]},
  {id: "sjdh5", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["try","test","test"]},
]
```

I want to remove the duplicate data. `id` does not matter

The expected result is:-

```
const myArray = [
  {id: "sjdh1", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["try","test","test"]},
  {id: "sjdh2", userName: "user 2"  , Message: ["test","try","test"]},
  {id: "sjdh3", userName: "user 3"  , Message: ["test"]}, 
  {id: "sjdh4", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["dummy"]}, 
]
```

Removing the value if the UserName and the Message array is completely Same if the Message array is different then the object should not be considered the duplicate one :

So, I tried to use the set method but I found that it is not working because myArray contains the object.

Then I googled the problem and got this solution but it didnot worked for me :-

```
 const uniqueValues = new Set(array.map(v => v.name));
```

It gives me the only one key with it's value

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should suffice for now:

```js
const myArray = [
    {id: "sjdh1", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["try","test","test"]},
    {id: "sjdh2", userName: "user 2"  , Message: ["test","try","test"]},
    {id: "sjdh3", userName: "user 3"  , Message: ["test"]}, 
    {id: "sjdh4", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["dummy"]},
    {id: "sjdh5", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["try","test","test"]},
  ]
function unique(){
    const uniqueKeys = ['userName','Message'];
    const keys = ['id'];
    const uniqueObj = {}
    myArray.forEach((arrObj)=>{
        const strKey = {};
        const strObj = {};
        uniqueKeys.forEach((k)=>{
            strKey[k] = arrObj[k]
        });
        keys.forEach((key)=>{
            strObj[key] = arrObj[key];
        })
        if(!uniqueObj[JSON.stringify(strKey)])
            uniqueObj[JSON.stringify(strKey)] = strObj;
    });
    const output = Object.keys(uniqueObj).map((key)=>{
        return {
            ...uniqueObj[key],
            ...JSON.parse(key)
        }
    })
    console.log(output);
}

unique();
```

Comment: can you explain you solution .

Comment: can you elaborate a little

Comment: yep you got it @Abishek Kumar

Comment: @Sarojregmi I basically did a string compare here with `JSON.stringify`, when I created the key.

Comment: and assigned the other value to that key, then iterated over that new object and created an array

Comment: @Sarojregmi mark it accepted if it worked for you, and comment if you need further clarification

Comment: other method might have a complexity of `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

We can check the array contents and also the order of the elements to check for the array equality.

Then using `Array#reduce` we can check which arrays were already seen during the iteration and not consider their index when filtering the original array:

```js
const myArray = [{id: "sjdh1", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["try","test","test"]}, {id: "sjdh2", userName: "user 2"  , Message: ["test","try","test"]}, {id: "sjdh3", userName: "user 3"  , Message: ["test"]}, {id: "sjdh4", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["dummy"]}, {id: "sjdh5", userName: "user 1"  , Message: ["try","test","test"]}];

const isArrEqual = (aOne, aTwo) => (aOne && aTwo) && (aOne.length === aTwo.length) && (aOne.every((e, i) => aTwo[i] === e));

const removeDups = (arr) => {
  const res = arr.reduce((r, o, i) => {
    //If the current array and userName is not seen before add it and its index
    if(!r.seen.some(({message, userName}) => isArrEqual(message, o.Message) && userName === o.userName)){
     r.seen.push({message: o.Message, userName: o.userName});
     r.idx.push(i);
    }
    return r;
  //Maintain an object which stores already visited arrays and their indexes
  }, {seen: [] , idx: []} );
  //Filter and return those arrays which occured only once
  return res.idx.map(i => arr[i]);
}
console.log(removeDups(myArray));
```

Comment: I guess OP wanted, the uniqueness on two keys `UserName` and `Message `.

Comment: @Sarojregmi I updated the answer and checked for both the `userName` and `Message` array. Please check if this works for you

Comment: @Saroj regmi please accept or upvote if you found it useful, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tried a concise approach

```js
const myArray = [{
    id: "sjdh1",
    userName: "user 1",
    Message: ["try", "test", "test"]
  },
  {
    id: "sjdh2",
    userName: "user 2",
    Message: ["test", "try", "test"]
  },
  {
    id: "sjdh3",
    userName: "user 3",
    Message: ["test"]
  },
  {
    id: "sjdh4",
    userName: "user 1",
    Message: ["dummy"]
  },
  {
    id: "sjdh5",
    userName: "user 1",
    Message: ["try", "test", "test"]
  },
]

function compareObj(obj1, obj2) {
  return obj1.Message.every((msg) => (obj2.Message.includes(msg))) && obj1.userName == obj2.userName;
}

function unique() {
  const uniqueArr = []
  myArray.forEach((arrObj) => {
    if (!uniqueArr.some((uObj) => compareObj(uObj, arrObj)))
      uniqueArr.push(arrObj);
  });
  console.log(uniqueArr);
}

unique();
```

Comment: @Sarojregmi here is another approach

Comment: nice Thank you this a little more easy and clear thank you sir